# python 2.7.13 coding language

Tags: python

I am getting this error over and over, could anyone please help me solve this? I have created a queue.json and stock.json files and it persists to give me the same error for both. I think I need to make these inputs so my whole code runs but this 5th line is preventing it.

## Import the json file import json #Use the Queue and Stock files and asign them accordingly with open("queue.json") as dataFile: Patient_Queue = json.load(dataFile) with open("stock.json") as dataFile: Medicine_Stock = json.load(dataFile)              and this next part is the error I always recieve.

========= RESTART: /Users/Aimee/Desktop/Task 2 Programming, CaolanD =========

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aimee/Desktop/Task 2 Programming, CaolanD", line 5, in 
    with open("queue.json") as dataFile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'queue.json'

Comment: it tells you that no file called 'queue.json' exists. It does so because you try to open a file with this name. Does this surprise you ? Check that your interpreter has the same working directory as the file you are trying to access.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Comment: _Where_ (in what directory) are the files you've created? From _where_ (what directory) are you running your code from? Are these directories the same? Python attempts to open this file from the directory you run the script from.

Comment: Please also read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to update your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: im only new to this language so I don't know much on what to do, this is the code I have and I think im trying to make inputs so that the code will run using these 2 json files.  #Import the json file
import json

#Use the Queue and Stock files and asign them accordingly
with open("queue.json") as dataFile:
    Patient_Queue = json.load(dataFile)

with open("stock.json") as dataFile:
    Medicine_Stock = json.load(dataFile)

Comment: Please edit additional information into your original question, so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: This is my code I have inputted and line 5 there is the same error no matter how many times I change it   #Import the json file
import json

#Use the Queue and Stock files and asign them accordingly
with open("queue.json") as dataFile:
    Patient_Queue = json.load(dataFile)

with open("stock.json") as dataFile:
    Medicine_Stock = json.load(dataFile)

Comment: and get this error every time. Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:40:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
========= RESTART: /Users/Aimee/Desktop/Task 2 Programming, CaolanD =========

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aimee/Desktop/Task 2 Programming, CaolanD", line 5, in <module>
    with open("queue.json") as dataFile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'queue.json'

Answer (score 2):

The file you created is probably not where your python script is looking for it. If you are not sure what is the path it looks for, you can print the full path (from within the same script) like this:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("queue.json"))
```

If it does exist in this path, make sure you have reading permissions for this file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct path to your file:

if you have a file that sits in the same directory as your program then calling the file should work fine the way you are calling it.

```
with open("queue.json") as dataFile:
```

If the file is located in a subfolder say one folder down then you need to specify the path.

```
with open("./FileFolder/queue.json") as dataFile:
```

Notice the `.` in front of `/FileFolder/`. This is used when the folder is in the same directory as the main program and allows you to avoid specifying a complete OS Path.

For a few reason you may need to specify the complete OS Path. Correct me if I am wrong but if the interpreter is not set to the same directory as the program it will need a complete path to the file.

something like:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\userName\\Documents\\Workspace\\Filefolder\\queue.json") as dataFile:
```

Thanks for bringing this to my attention `Christian König`. As Chris Mentioned in the comments you need to escape the `\` or the interpreter will read it as unicode. the way to escape a backslash is to just put another backslash.

Comment: Notice that you have to escape the \ in your path to \\, or otherwise Python will try to interpret `\Users` as a unicode character and throw an error.

Answer (score -2):

You put queue.json in the wrong place.

Python is looking for it in the *current working directory* of the executing shell.

Comment: I look forward to hearing how this is wrong.

Comment: this is not _wrong_, but that was probably too short for an answer and would look better as a comment.

Comment: @ForceBru: No, technical answers should **never** be written as comments, regardless of length. The comments section is for requesting clarification from the OP; nothing more.

Comment: @ForceBru There's no length minimum for an answer. If it's an answer, it's an answer. There's rules for link only answers, but that's a different problem.

Comment: @TankorSmash, are there rules for whether one must upvote some answer or downvote it? Votes represent _personal opinion_ only.

Comment: @ForceBru: While you are certainly free to cast your vote however you like, it should be self-evident that the system works best when we all follow best practice guidelines. You may hover your mouse cursor over the downvote icon to see how the feature is _intended_ to be used. If you wish to go off and use the voting system completely differently, nobody can stop you (short of serial vote fraud, that is!). Certainly your assertion that this should have been a comment is wrong, opinion or otherwise.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, this is what the Help Center says about voting: "Voting up a question or answer signals <...> while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is _poorly researched_, or _fails to communicate information_." Note how now your answer doesn't attract more downvotes because you've added the crucial detail that might actually _help_ the OP to solve the problem. But in the _first few seconds_ it consisted of only one _obvious_ sentence, basically the error message rephrased.

Comment: @ForceBru: Right, and this answer doesn't contain wrong information, isn't poorly researched, and doesn't fail to communicate information. So while, again, I support your right to vote as you choose, let's not pretend that you are voting in accordance with community guidelines.

Comment: @ForceBru: _"basically the error message rephrased"_ Not really; it created the connection "the file doesn't exist" -> "actually it does, just not in the right place" that the OP was missing. Literally the key point of the question! Have a nice day